# What is the exit code of the MacOS /usr/bin/python3 stub?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

If you run `/usr/bin/python3` on a MacOS system that has yet to install the system python3 it pops up a dialog that says: "*Xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at*"...

Now unfortunately, on my macmini I've previously run this command, and so the `/usr/bin/python3` stub has been replaced by the real python (python 3.8.9), and short of reseting/reinstall my mac I don't know how to get it back.

So my question is, **what's the exit code for the `/usr/bin/python3` stub**?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to check in a script if the system python3 is installed or not, and checking the return code, would be more reliable / easier than comparing the strings in stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives an exit code of 1, see below :

[image]